# BsModalModule error TS2339: Property 'open' does not exist on type 'BsModalModule'

Tags: angular, angular5

Currently I am learning Angular 4 Application;  I am trying to add model window for adding records. For this I have created model in page. Also I have installed `ng2-bs3-modal` package from NPM. I am using VS code for implementing Application.

My component class is importing below reference for

```
import { BsModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal';
```

Called in `myComponent`  view reference as follows:

```
the export class myComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('modal') modal : BsModalModule;
```

function for adding data,

```
adddata() {  
    this.dbops = DBOperation.create;  

    this.Frm.reset();  
    this.modal.open();
}
```

in the HTML page.

```
<modal #modal>  
my form code here.
</modal>
```

But when I try to run the project, I get this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'open' does not exist on type 'BsModalModule'.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I have tried to format your code and improve the spelling, but this was really not clear, so please double check and edit your question so that it is clearer, including for its code snippets.

Comment: Hello Thanks for comment. 

I am creating new application in angular and Core.Net. I Have created WebAPI. 
Now i am working on angular application. I am trying to follow below article. 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-2-crud-operations-with-web-api-and-entity-framework/

But while implementing application I am facing Issue which i asked here.

When I am generating the application I am getting error mentioned above,

Thanks in Advance.
Omkar.

Answer (score 0):

Use BsModalComponent instead of BsModalModule

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29960167)